# How to call a method inside selenium function

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, webdriver

Over the past couple of days, I have built a very simplistic python webscraper using selenium that scrapes a certain car listing website and gathers listing data about a specific make and model of a car. However, I am having an issue with referencing a method inside a selenium method.

```
class crawler:
    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.car_make = make
        self.car_model = model
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/ecc/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get("car-listing-website")
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='carPickerUsed_makerSelect']").click()
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(), {self.car_make}]").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='carPickerUsed_modelSelect']").click()
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(), {self.car_model})]").click()
```

The problem I am having is referencing the self.car_make and self.car_model values inside the last few lines of code:

```
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(), {self.car_make}]").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='carPickerUsed_modelSelect']").click()
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(), {self.car_model})]").click()
```

After this runs, it says that these are not valid Xpath expressions. I guess my question is, can this even be accomplished within selenium? If so, is it just a matter of a syntax error?

For context, the goal is to be able to use crawler() instances to be able to scrape any type of make & model on the website without having to manually update the code to search for those different makes and models. For example, ideally, you would be able to use the following code to get listing data for Ford Mustangs:

```
crawler('Ford','Mustang')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not very experienced with selenium, but maybe try this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//option[contains(text(), '{self.car_make}')]").click()
```

Or this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//option[text()='{self.car_make}')]").click()
```

If not, try sharing the piece of Html you're having trouble with.

Comment: You could also use explicit wait instead of time.sleep().

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up figuring out a solution. I used the format() method to pass in the values for self.car_make and self.car_model after the Xpath strings. Did the trick